# How to handle many tabs

Tags: usability, website-design, navigation, information-architecture, tabs

If we try to create a page which contains tons of data about each employee.
These data are categorized in tabs and every tab opens nested tabs! 
The tabs appearance looks overwhelming especially after adding the styles and they appear in multi-lines!

Could I ask how to handle all these data in easy way for the end user ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A ton of Tabs mean, lack of usability, and you may hide important information too.

Categories your Tabs and create a main menu, navigation menu or some kind of indexed links.
Then use Tab options for the user to navigate the different information on each tab.

**Employee data**

***1.Personal***

Address - Tab 01

Contact - Tab 02

***2.Qualifications***

Certificates - Tab 01

Bachelor - Tab 02

***3.Finance***

Tax number -Tab 01

Bank account -Tab 02

Comment: In short - group the tabs and add more levels of subcategories. It's not that every information needs to be max. 2 clicks away as long as it is logically found. You can also perform some analysis and bring the most used tabs to the top.

Comment: @Mike, exactly yes!

Answer (score 2):

It is ideal to not hide so much information behind tabs. Users won't be able to find the information quickly and easily. It may be a great idea to regroup things to just a handful of tabs and lay out the information differently so that it is more scannable. The more clear the information is grouped, the quicker the user can find what they are looking for.